# Keep user logged in without AsyncStorage

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm using firebase inside my application for auth, I want the user to stay logged in after registration or logging in.

I heard about AsyncStorage but I noticed it is not recommended to save data such as passwords with it.
I thought about saving the firebase auth token or something to keep the user logged in, but I really don't know where to start.

Is it the best way to do it?
If so, where can I start?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here I saw that it is not recommended to store sensitive data (such as password) with AsyncStorage

https://medium.com/@ntoscano/react-native-persistent-user-login-6a48ff380ab8

Comment: Edit your question to add references to what you've read and where those recommendations came from. Without it, it's very hard for people to understand what you do know and don't or where you might have misunderstood something.

Comment: @MichaelCheng Thanks, i edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the user has logged in successfully, firebase will return the current user in response of **firebase.auth().currentUser**.

Check the value of it and you can set a boolean flag depending upon this value. You can mantain the session using that flag now.

Hope this answers your question.